# hadoop: how to replace zlib without rebuild hadoop or affecting other applications

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, hadoop2, zlib

I am a newbie to Hadoop configuration. The requirement is let hadoop run compression/decompression towards a customized zlib. Here're something I tried:

1. Specified the customized zlib path, and re-compile hadoop. This is not I want since it requires compilation.
2. Adding my zlib to the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This is also not a good way because my lib will pollute the environment and I do not want any other applications except hadoop to use my own lib.

My question is, is there a proper way to specify zlib path for hadoop without compilation and polluting environment? Maybe there's some configuration file can do this? Thanks in advance for your help.